# Smoke simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation, collision

So i have this ventilation shaft with gate that closes. I was trying to get some to interact with gate closing but smoke still goes trough gate. And yes gate has collision (sampling 1 and thickness 1).
Is there some secret setting i dont know?[image]

[image]

Comment: Smoke simulations are complex and have lots of settings, many of them important for the result. A simple overview screenshot of the scene is not enough information to rule out every possible issue with this. You are not even showing the issue how it looks with the smoke. Then I have no idea if all normals of the object are correct, scale applied, what resolution the domain has etc. Probably it would be best to upload your file to https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4wnxaa7V" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4wnxaa7V/)

Here is file

Comment: The computer on which I am now is to weak to simulate this in an appropriate time, however I am now on frame 60. The smoke goes through the open gate, but not through the closed gate and not through the backside of the shaft as you can see here: [smoke sim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5No4.jpg). My images are in _Solid_ view, in your file the viewport was set to _Material Preview_, which uses _EEVEE_ and is bad at handling smoke, I guess what you have seen are artifacts from the bad volumetrics settings in _EEVEE_.

Comment: more important are frame from 120 to 180. Closing and opening. Thank you for testing this.

Comment: Well, then I would have to check that later on a computer which can simulate this faster. Still I can see smoke already coming through the closed gate when I switch to _Material Preview_, where it definitely is not and only looks like this in this accursed _EEVEE_.

Comment: So i tested again and yes, the side that is closed works but when other side closes smoke does not interact with it just goes trough. Weird.

Comment: I just saw one of the gate blades has the _Use Effector_ option disabled in its settings. Maybe that's where the smoke comes through?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8uF1xIa here is what is see

Comment: In that image, the second blade from the left is disabled as Effector, so it will not hold the smoke back.

Answer (score 0):

In your scene, you have (probably accidentally) disabled the *Use Effector* option on one of the gate blades (the second to the right of the smoke emitter. That's why it does not block the smoke after the gate is closed (and it means there's also more smoke coming through the open gate than it should).

This blade has the *Use Effector* option disabled:

[image: effector disabled]

After re-enabling it and letting the simulation run, the smoke does no longer get past the gate when it gets closed. This is on frame 165:

[image: effector re-enabled]

Comment: OMG. 8hrs i tried to find solution. And thank you very much!

Comment: @DenyBoyLV You're welcome. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)